# flowtype marks individual package import as not found

Tags: eslint, flowtype

I'm trying to begin using Flowtype but when importing sub packages, e.g.

```
import isArray from 'lodash/isArray';
```

my eslint is complaining that the required module not found.

I already used `flow-typed install` to install all lib defs that can be found.

Any idea on how to tackle this?

Thanks!

Comment: does it work when you do `import { isArray } from 'lodash'`? it doesn't look like the flow libdef handles the module name 'lodash/isArray'

Comment: @LewisChung Sorry for the delay, yes it *does* work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flow is treating `lodash/isArray` as it's own module so it needs to be told what the exports of that module are.

Modify the `lodash` libdef to export `lodash/isArray` also.

You can do this like this (I extracted out a subset of the libdef and showed you what would need to change)

```
declare module 'lodash/isArray' {
  declare function isArray(value: any): bool;

  declare module.exports: typeof isArray
}

declare module 'lodash' {
  declare class Lodash {
    isArray: $Exports<'lodash/isArray'>
  }

  declare var exports: Lodash;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

If it's normal for people to load lodash modules the way you're doing it, the whole libdef should be updated to support this use case.

Answer (score 0):

First, Flow is not ESLint. They are two separate tools. `flow-typed install` will typically not affect ESLint errors.

Based on the information in your question, I see two possiblities:

1. You haven't actually installed `lodash`. Make sure it is listed as a dependency in your `package.json` and run `npm install`.
2. You are somehow piping Flow errors through ESLint (though I do not recommend this), and there is an issue with the `flow-typed` libdef for `lodash`. In that case you will likely need to figure out how to tweak the libdef to allow this.

Comment: Thanks Nat. 1) lodash is indeed with `npm i -S` 2) so there *is* an issue between flow-typed libdef and lodash, which is the core of this root of this question, how can one "tweak the libdef t oallow this".